# When to go peer to peer to an actual server for small business?

Tags: windows-7

I've been asked by a small business to help them with their network setup when they moving to a new location. Currently everything is peer to peer with a tcp/ip printer.

At what point is it worth migrating to something like linux or windows server?  They have one windows 8 machine that is just sharing documents.  Only has like 8 employees. Is it overkill or should i just stick with peer to peer?

Comment: 5 workstations, if the system administrator to pay)

Answer (score 1):

This question is really opinion based, it might get closed.

However, it is a good question.  The answer is very simple:  Move to a client/server system based when you *need* to.

That *need* is something that you and your client need to determine for yourselves.  That need will become more and more apparent on its own.  Logins becoming an issue?  Need centralized and audited storage?  Updates becoming an issue?  Etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is some middle ground to be considered also.

Could the needs for file sharing be satisfied with:

- a set of [Dropbox for Business](https://www.dropbox.com/business) subscriptions?
- a [NAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage)?
- is the company in question using Office and/or Exchange? Why not port them to [Office365](https://products.office.com/en-US/business/compare-office-365-for-business-plans), which will give you (depending on the chosen plan) possibilities of [Sharepoint](https://products.office.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-online-collaboration-software) and [OneDrive for Business](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-us/business/)

There is a lot of other options out there as well. But the ones outlined above are well-known, widely used, low cost and, most importantly *really* easy to set up.